# Fire ul tag click event not li with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can affect click event only ul tag not all li with jQuery?

```
<!-- HTML -->
<ul class="wrap">
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test2</li>
    <li>test3</li>
</ul>
```

I tried jquery like this.But it doesnt work.

```
//Javascript
jQuery("ul.wrap").not(jQuery("ul > li")).click(function(){
      //fire only ul
});
```

How can we do this?

Comment: But ul will have li after all.What do u mean by Click on ul

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v5eh8/1/ Check this fiddle.UL has LI so thought you click on li , it will be as if UL is clicked

Comment: I mean jquery click event will affect except all li.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Events 'bubble' up the DOM to their parent elements. What you need to do is attach the event to the `ul`, and another event on the child `li` elements which uses `stopPropagation()`:

```
jQuery("ul.wrap")
    .on('click', function(){
        // do something...
    })
    .on('click', 'li', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Rory McCrossan. This is working perfectly. I try to use this in modal.Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can simply do it with this code:

```
jQuery('.wrap').click(function (event) {    
    if ( !$(event.target).is( "li" ) ) {
        console.log('ul clicked!');
    } 
});
```

You can see an example with background colors that shows the ul and the li here: http://jsfiddle.net/S67Uu/2/