# Set onClick action for button in each UL block jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 10 (ul) blocks, and they are built dynamically with $windows.onLoad, in each block I have list of terms (li). Some terms in each block must be invisible at first.  All actions I do only in script, with jQuery selectors.

```
window).load(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@controllers.blog.routes.BlogController.allBlogTerms()',
                type: 'get',
                success: function (terms) {

                    var urlPrefix = "@translateUrl(controllers.blog.routes.BlogController.termItem("").url)";
                    for (var l = 0; l < terms.length; l++) {
                        $('.list_of_terms').append('<div class="item col-md-4">\
                                <div class="inner_item">\
                                <div class="capital">\
                                ' + terms[l].letter + '\
                                </div>\
                                <ul class="ul' + l + '">\
                                </ul>\
                                </div>\
                                </div>\
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>');
                        for (var t = 0; t <= terms[l].terms.length - 1; t++) {
                            if (t > 5)
                                $('.ul' + l).append('<li style="display:none;"><a href="' + urlPrefix + terms[l].terms[t].url + '">' + terms[l].terms[t].title + '</a></li>');
                            else
                                $('.ul' + l).append('<li><a href="' + urlPrefix + terms[l].terms[t].url + '">' + terms[l].terms[t].title + '</a></li>');
                        }
```

So I create buttons on these blocks to manage visibility of lists in it.
But I have a problem with coupling each button with each block. When I press it on some block - it shows content of 'li' in ALL blocks.

```
 $.fn.myFunc = function() {

                                $('li').show();
                        };


                        $('.ul' + l).append('<button type="button" onclick="$(this).myFunc(????);">Canada</button>');
```

When I try to pass parameter "l" (which means number of block), it can not identify it in scope (where now question marks).
So how can I parametrize my buttons so that they can act only on UL they are located

Comment: you question is not so clear. Are you trying to create a button that shows the content of a particular li ?

Comment: I think this answer will help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342573/fire-ul-tag-click-event-not-li-with-jquery

Comment: Of ALL li that are in the block where the button locates. To be more clear - it is an alphabet of terms - i have 28 UL-s and 28 buttons - so when i press a button i'd like to see all words on ONE specific letter (UL)

Comment: @HeidiYatom Thanks, but i dont have a conflict between ul and li. It is about multiple UL-s themself. They have buttons and each button act on ALL ul, not just on one it is bound to. I just can not parametrize onClick action with id of specific UL. Or maybe there is more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('li').show();
```

will show all the li elements on the page.

I hope this example will help you:

```
<body>
    <ul class='ul1'>
      <li>Argentina</li>
      <li>Albania</li>
      <li>Australia</li>
    </ul>

    <ul class='ul2'>
     <li>Belgium</li>
     <li>Bangladesh</li>
     <li>Bahrain</li>
   </ul>
 </body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    // the button click event handler
    function showItems(){
      // get the class attribute of the ul element 
      // (assuming it has 1 class only):
      var ul = $(this).parent().attr('class');

      // create a selector using the id of the ul $(.ul1 li), $(.ul2 li):
      $('.'+ul+' li').show();
    }

    // add buttons to the lists:
    $('.ul1').prepend('<button type="button" class="btn">A</button>');
    $('.ul2').prepend('<button type="button" class="btn"">B</button>');
    $('li').hide();

    // bind the showItems click event handler to the buttons:
    $(document).on('click', '.btn', showItems);
```

Comment: Oh my God, it worked!! Thank you VERY MUCH, @HeidiYatom! What i did, is just wrote this var ul = $(this).parent().attr('class');
                                $('.'+ul+' li').show();

And changed nothing more.    One more question (if it's not much of a trouble)  How to make it bach invisible again - like show/hide ??

Comment: simply use toggle() instead of show() on the li element

Comment: Thanks again, @HeidiYatom! It worked fine. The last question, and maybe the simpliest one - after i click - on button - it indeed opens content of block, but when i click ones more to hide it - it hides, BUT - it moves browser screen down to the bottom blocks. Maybe some simple advice to avoid it? :)